# Half Fps (OpenGL) after doing a single selection (GL_SELECT mode)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I know that OpenGL selection mode is deprecated and never was HW accelerated, except on a few SGI boxes and 3DLabs GPUs.But i can't get rid of it (not my code).

With a specific draw,i get about 125 frames/second.But when I have a (or more) Hit(s) (so Selection mode works) and I try to move the camera as usual,I get like 40-50 frames/second.If there aren't Hits at all,nothing strange happens and I have the same good framerate.

What am I doing wrong?

Below its the C++ code:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

gluLookAt(objCamera->mPos.x,  objCamera->mPos.y,  objCamera->mPos.z,
          0, objCamera->mView.y, 0,
          objCamera->mUp.x,   objCamera->mUp.y,   objCamera->mUp.z);        

ourRender(scene);
}
```

startSelection is invoked by Qt mousePressEvent

```
void GLWidget::startSelection(int x,int y)                                                                 // This Is Where Selection Is Done
{
GLint viewport[4];

glSelectBuffer(BUFSIZE,selectBuf);
glRenderMode(GL_SELECT);
glInitNames();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,viewport);
gluPickMatrix(x,viewport[3]-y,5,5,viewport);
gluPerspective(fov,ratio,0.1f,1000);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

draw_something();
stopSelection();
}



void GLWidget::stopSelection() {

int hits;
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);      // restoring the original projection matrix
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
hits = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER);      // returning to normal rendering mode
if (hits > 0){
    qDebug() << "Found " << hits << " hit(s)";
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see why it should be slow, but I think you're going to have to explain which parts you *can* change and why the others are out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With a specific draw,i get about 125 frames/second.But when I have a (or more) Hit(s) (so Selection mode works) and I try to move the camera as usual,I get like 40-50 frames/second.If there aren't Hits at all,nothing strange happens and I have the same good framerate.

Think about it: No hits means, nothing must be pushed onto the selection name stack. It could very well be, that the SW implementation of selection mode allocates the name stack only when there's an actual hit, i.e. the primitive would get rastered in the clip volume. Memory allocation is a costly operation.

Now your rendering code will have to push IDs on the namestack, and if it does this also in the "visible" render path it might interact with the memory allocation of the selection mode.

This is all pure (educated) guesswork, though.

> What am I doing wrong?

I'd not say "wrong" but "unhappy". I'd introduce a flag to the scene rendering code, to not push IDs on the name stack, if not in selection mode.

Answer (score -8):

I see that you forgot to initialize the Frame Buffer Data,
Right now you are allocating space for the frames in real time which makes the computation time 10x longer than what it would normally be. This can easily be fixed.

Also, I suggest you change this:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

gluLookAt(objCamera->mPos.x,  objCamera->mPos.y,  objCamera->mPos.z,
          0, objCamera->mView.y, 0,
          objCamera->mUp.x,   objCamera->mUp.y,   objCamera->mUp.z);        

ourRender(scene);
}
```

Into this:

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glBufferInfluxinatorPrep(scene);
gluLookAt(objCamera->mPos.x,  objCamera->mPos.y,  objCamera->mPos.z,
          0, objCamera->mView.y, 0,
          objCamera->mUp.x,   objCamera->mUp.y,   objCamera->mUp.z);        
ourRender(scene);
glBufferDefluxinator(scene);
}
```

Hope I helped, Thanks.

Comment: Is this a joke? This not helpful at all.

Comment: Nothing of what you wrote makes any sense. OP doesn't have problems caused by "allocating space for a frame". WTF is `glBufferInfluxinatorPrep` supposed to be? That's not a OpenGL function. What you wrote there is totally worthless *gibberish*.

Comment: It is an OpenGL function, maybe you use an old version of OpenGL.

Comment: @AlexTheCoder: Because [OpenGL.org](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/) and google do not know about it, there's no such function.

Comment: @AlexTheCoder: It's definitely not an OpenGL function. I got the specifications of all OpenGL versions and of all extensions stored on my computer. I can do a mass search over them and none of the official OpenGL specification document this.

Comment: @AlexTheCoder: Google must be doing something wrong as well. I'm going to assume you're some sort of troll unless you manage to produce a documentation link for that mythical function.

Comment: @AlexTheCoder: You're the one claiming it to exist. So please provide a reference to said function. All the official OpenGL documentation is available through http://www.opengl.org/registry – OpenGL-4 (the most recent) reference manuals are available at http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/ – so humor us.

Comment: I have to remember this one for the future... I never knew I was supposed to initialize my flux capacitor each frame.